# Knockout JS visible based on select value

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to show or hide a paragraph based on the value of a `select`. I have reviewed the various posts that seem the same as my question however, I am new to knockout.js and none of them seem to give a basic simple example of what I am trying to do.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/scooke/ub8ozbvf/

Answer (score 1):

you can use the ko if comment.

in your case:

```
<!-- ko if: multipleSelectedOptionValues() == "Alpha" -->
        <p>show or hide</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I think I pasted in the wrong fiddle at first but then revised it. Here is the revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scooke/ub8ozbvf/

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes on your code:

1. Javascript: on json objects, the key-value pairs are separated by comma not by semicolons

   ```
   var testing = {
     currentSelect: ko.observable("apples"),
     otherKey: ko.observable("otherValue"),
   }
   ```
2. HTML data-bind tags: as you are using a ko.observable to test equality, you have to call it as a function and you don't have to break the simple quotation mark inside double quotation mark

`<p data-bind="visible:currentSelect() === 'apples'">Apples Shown!</p>`

I've update your fiddle

Comment: I'm new on jsfiddle, so this is the link to the modified version, I suppose: http://jsfiddle.net/ub8ozbvf/24/